# $\dim (\ker f \cap \ker g) = n-2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Let $V$ a vector subspace of dimension $n$ on $\mathbb R$ and $f,g \in V^* \backslash \{0\}$ two linearly independent linear forms. I want to show that $\dim (\ker f \cap \ker g) = n-2$.

Since $f$ and $g$ are linear forms, I know that dim ker $f =n-1$ and dim ker $g =n-1$. I think I should use the fact that the two forms are linearly independent to $\dim (\ker f \cap \ker g) = n-2$ but I don't really see how...

I saw a proof with scalar product but I would like to see an alternative proof or maybe an explanation of the scalar product's proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $f,g$ are linearly independent, $\ker f +\ker g=\mathbb{R}^n$.

$\dim(\ker f+\ker g) =\dim\ker f +\dim\ker g-\dim(\ker f\cap\ker g)$ implies that

$n = n-1+n-1-\dim(\ker f\cap\ker g)$, and $\dim(\ker f\cap\ker g)=n-2$.

Comment: Could you explain why the first equality is true?

Comment: This is a general result on vector subspaces, $dim(A+B)=dimA+dimB-dim A\cap B$.   Here $A =Ker f, B=Ker g$ and $A+B=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Same question as @BokaPeer, can you please detail the first sentence please "$\ker f + \ker g = \mathbb R^n$"?

Comment: My question was why $Ker f +Ker g = V$.

Comment: If $Ker f=Ker g$, consider $x$ which is not in $Ker f$, and such that $f(x)=1, g=g(x)f$. Contradiction,there exists $y\in Ker g$ not in $Ker f$ implies that $Ker f+Ker g=\mathbb{R}^n$ because of the dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

The following post contains the key part of the proof of your problem. Tsemo has mentioned it in his comment.

[Proving that linear functionals are linearly independent if and only if their kernels are different](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1088623/304326)

A bit more explanation/belaboring:

From this above post, you conclude that $\ker f \cap\ker g$ strictly contained in $\ker f$  and $\ker g$. Then we have the following:
$$
\dim (\ker f + \ker g) =  n-1 + (\dim\ker f -\dim (\ker f \cap\ker g).$$ Since $ (\ker f -\dim (\ker f \cap\ker g )>0$, we have $\dim(\ker f +\ker g)$
is strictly greater than $n-1$. This shows that $\ker f +\ker g = V.$ by the way, I assumed that $\dim (V) = n > 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Consider the linear maps $h : V \to \mathbb R^2$ and $\tilde h : \mathbb R^2 \to V^*$ given by $h(v) = (f(v),g(v))$ for all $v \in V$ and $\tilde h(a,b) = af+bg$ for all $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$. Prove that $h$ is surjective if $\tilde h$ is injective (*hint*: find an isomorphism $\psi : (\mathbb R^2)^* \to \mathbb R^2$ such that the tranpose of $h$ can be written as $\tilde h \circ \psi$). Thus, the linear independence of $f$ and $g$ shows that $h$ is surjective, and clearly $\ker h = \ker f \cap \ker g$. Finally, use the rank-nullity theorem on $h$.